# html5 canvas toDataURL returns blank image

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

i am using following code to draw canvas and save it as png image using toDataUrl.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
      #myCanvas {
        border: 1px solid #9C9898;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      function loadImages(sources, callback) {
        var images = {};
        var loadedImages = 0;
        var numImages = 0;
        // get num of sources
        for(var src in sources) {
          numImages++;
        }
        for(var src in sources) {
          images[src] = new Image();
          images[src].onload = function() {
            if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
              callback(images);
            }
          };
          images[src].src = sources[src];
        }
      }

      window.onload = function(images) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        var sources = {
          darthVader: "http://a1.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/228564_449431448422343_1996991887_n.jpg",
          yoda: "http://a4.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/427489_449423165089838_503188418_n.jpg"
        };

        loadImages(sources, function(images) {
          context.drawImage(images.darthVader, 250, 30, 250, 250);
          context.drawImage(images.yoda, 530, 30, 250, 250);
        });


// save canvas image as data url (png format by default)
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

        // set canvasImg image src to dataURL
        // so it can be saved as an image
        document.getElementById("canvasImg").src = dataURL;
};


    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="850" height="315"></canvas>
<img id="canvasImg" alt="Right click to save me!">
  </body>
</html>
```

But my png image is shown as blank image. i see only a blank white image.
i searched for this but found nothing on this.
i am using php and chrome browser.
what is wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Canvas toDataURL returns blank](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31193418/html5-canvas-todataurl-returns-blank)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are first calling `loadImages`, then getting the data URL right after that `loadImages` *call*. However, as your `loadImages` implementation shows, calling it merely starts the loading process; the callback is called when all images *have been loaded*, which is some time in the future.

Currently you're getting a blank image because the images have not been loaded yet, so your callback is not called yet, and as a result your canvas is still empty.

In short, everything that relies on the images having being loaded (e.g. your expected `toDataURL` result) should be executed when those images are actually loaded - thus in the callback.

```
loadImages(sources, function(images) {
  context.drawImage(images.darthVader, 250, 30, 250, 250);
  context.drawImage(images.yoda, 530, 30, 250, 250);

  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
  document.getElementById("canvasImg").src = dataURL;
});
```

Comment: nothing happens when i add this into the callback. not even the src is set to DataURL

Comment: @Badal Surana: Are the images painted on the canvas? Any errors in the console?

Comment: There's an error in the console. You're drawing images from other websites, and as a security measure you cannot get the data URL. You could host the images on your own domain instead.