# HTML5 Canvas toDataURL returns blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I wanted to upload the image files, draw them into canvas, make changes and save it in the database. I tried to test the base64 value that the canvas image (`Pic`) returned, and it is blank. However, I see the result when I append the canvas (`Pic`) to the document. What am I doing wrong here?

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object                
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

    if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
      continue;
    }
    // read contents of files asynchronously
    var reader = new FileReader();

    // Closure to capture the file information.
    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
      return function(e) {

        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

        var datauri = event.target.result,
          ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
          img = new Image();

        img.onload = function() {

          canvas.width = width;
          canvas.height = height;
          ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
        };
        img.src = datauri;
        var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        document.body.appendChild(canvas); //picture gets uploaded                    

        // Generate the image data

        var Pic = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

        console.log(Pic); // => returns base64 value which when tested equivalent to blank                              
        Pic = Pic.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "")

        // Sending image to Server
        $.ajax({
          // …
        });

      };
    })(f);
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is the object parameter of your `$.ajax` call (which is `// Sending image to Server`) empty? Please add a comment if you intentionally skipped some lines.

Comment: Does `console.log(Pic);` output anything?

Comment: yes, it gives some base 64 value which I tested is basically blank:

Comment: @Xufox: that's not an issue

Comment: Why do you apply `replace()` on `Pic`? Can't you do this on server?

Comment: @hindmost: I suppose I could but that doesn't change the issue I'm having.

Comment: Most likely the issue is in the `$.ajax()` options

Comment: I think, everything from `var imageData = …` should go into the `img.onload` function. The image needs to load in order to draw it to the canvas (which is done correctly) but also, the canvas needs to have the image to get a URL from it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

My intuition says that everything from `var imageData = …` should go into the `img.onload` function.

That means, at the relevant part the code becomes:

```
img.onload = function() {
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

  var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  document.body.appendChild(canvas); //picture gets uploaded                    

  // Generate the image data

  var Pic = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

  console.log(Pic); // => returns base64 value which when tested equivalent to blank                              
  Pic = Pic.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "")

  // Sending image to Server
  $.ajax({
    // …
  });
};
img.src = datauri;
```

The reason is that the line

```
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
```

correctly executes after the image has been loaded. But unfortunately, you don’t wait for loading when this line gets executed:

```
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

and all subsequent lines.

The image needs to be loaded in order to draw it on the canvas. The canvas needs to contain the loaded image in order to call `getImageData`.

Comment: I had so many weird issues by not using the onload function. Using that fixes everything for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution to get the `base64` code

Instead of this line:

```js
var Pic = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

use this:

```js
var Pic = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").split(',')[1];
```