# Can't get image to repeat on Canvas using repeat Pattern

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create a simple repeat image on canvas using a graphic I created myself.  Unfortunately createPattern(img, repeat) is resulting in only one version of the image being repeated.  I've tried saving it as an image and then loading that image using img.src, I've also tried creating a second canvas and tried to draw on that using the first canvas as the basis of the pattern but both are producing the same result - just one version of the image.  What am I missing here?

Here are both versions of my code:

Using two canvases:

```
function draw() {

  var canvas1 = document.getElementById('drawcanvas')
  var ctx = canvas1.getContext('2d');
  var canvas2 = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');


  ctx.fillStyle = '#f5f2d0';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 205, 255);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#FFF';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 250);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#77d499';
  ctx.fillRect(5, 5, 195, 245);
  var img = new Image();
  img.addEventListener('load', function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 48.75, 20, 100, 200)
  }, false)
  img.src = 'Images/wine-icon-15966.png';

  var pattern = ctx2.createPattern(canvas, 'repeat');
  ctx2.fillStyle = pattern;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 2480, 3508);
}
```

Using a separate image:

```
function draw() {

  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

  ctx.fillStyle = '#f5f2d0';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 2480, 3508);


  ctx.fillStyle = '#FFF';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 250);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#77d499';
  ctx.fillRect(5, 5, 195, 245);
  var img = new Image();
  img.addEventListener('load', function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 48.75, 20, 100, 200)
  }, false)
  img.src = 'Images/wine-icon-15966.png';

}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Canvas toDataURL returns blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31193418/html5-canvas-todataurl-returns-blank)

Comment: By the time you call `ctx2.createPattern(canvas,...` `img`'s `load` event has not fired yet. So you don't have any image drawn on the `canvas` you use as source for the pattern i.e you are creating a pattern from a still transparent image. Move all your logic inside this load even handler.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately I still can't get it to work - half the image disappears.  But I'll keep working on it with this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of tweaking and got it working using the draw from canvas option.  As suggested, I moved the logic inside the load statement.  I'd also referred to canvas in createPattern which is the id of the second canvas rather than the id I'd given the first canvas (drawcanvas) which meant I was essentially drawing a blank canvas onto a blank canvas. Here's my updated code.

```
function draw() {

  var canvas1 = document.getElementById('drawcanvas')
  var ctx = canvas1.getContext('2d');
  var canvas2 = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');


  ctx.fillStyle = '#f5f2d0';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 205, 255);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#FFF';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 250);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#77d499';
  ctx.fillRect(5, 5, 195, 245);
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'Images/wine-icon-15966.png';
    img.addEventListener('load', function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 48.75, 20, 100, 200);
    var pattern = ctx2.createPattern(drawcanvas, 'repeat');
    ctx2.fillStyle = pattern;
    ctx2.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx2.fill();

  }, false);

  ctx2.fillStyle = '#f5f2d0';
  ctx2.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```