# HTML canvas dataURL output is blank when using multiple images

Tags: html, canvas

I am trying to add multiple images to a HTML canvas and then get a file that I can save using `toDataURL()`

I have this so far

```js
const canvas  = document.querySelector("canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

myImage = new Image();
myImage.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/150";

myImage2 = new Image();
myImage2.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/250";

myImage3 = new Image();
myImage3.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/350";

myImage.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
  context.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, 100, 100);
});

myImage2.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
  context.drawImage(myImage2, 150, 0, 100, 100);
});

myImage3.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
  context.drawImage(myImage3, 300, 0, 100, 100);
});

var final = canvas.toDataURL();
console.log(final);
```

```html
<canvas width="800"></canvas>
```

The image is generated in the canvas correctly and I can see it looks ok, but the dataurl output is blank, where am I going wrong?

I know there are solutions when using one image like at [HTML5 Canvas toDataURL returns blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31193418/html5-canvas-todataurl-returns-blank) but as I am using multiple images, I am unsure how to apply this solution in my case

Comment: The dataURL is showing correctly in your code snippet tho... you might want to check on your local code if you're running into a CORS issue: when a canvas is considered to be tainted by the browser, then calling `toDataUrl()` will result in an error: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image

Comment: You have to wait for all images to load before calling `canvas.toDataUrl`... I was posting a solution but the question got closed.